# Beeswarm Honeypot Setup

Tags: honeypot

I am working on a POC of Beeswarm and I'm running into an issue with connecting the drone. For the basic setup, I have the server working fine and I can access it via https://X.X.X.X:5000 (I get a certificate error due to accepting the defaults). When I setup another server on the same subnet, I run the following command and get an error.

```
user@beeswarm-sensor1:/opt/drone_workdir$ sudo beeswarm --config https://X.X.X.X:5000/ws/drone/add/0f74fe
2014-09-03 16:12:24,681 (root) Initializing BeeSwarm version 0.4.17
2014-09-03 16:12:24,688 (requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool) Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 10.6.13.238
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:730: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html (This warning will only appear once by default.)
  InsecureRequestWarning)
2014-09-03 16:12:24,704 (root) Error while extracting configuration from https://X.X.X.X:5000/ws/drone/add/0f74fe, please make sure that the correct url was provided.
```

I'm assuming this is due to the certificate error but I don't see any reference on Beeswarm's documentation that this is an issue for anyone else. Since this is just a quick POC I didn't want to deal with creating certs and whatnot.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Have you seen this line: `please make sure that the correct url was provided`? Try to access that URL on your browser to see if it is correct.

Comment: It looks like it's a database error on the Beeswarm server. After calling a default.py script I get an OpertaionalError that says "attempt to write a readonly database".

Comment: I am the lead developer on the Beeswarm project, if you can reproduce these errors - could you please raise them as issues on our github page(https://github.com/honeynet/beeswarm/issues)?

Comment: The issue was that I did "sudo mkdir /opt/server_workdir" and then I ran "sudo beeswarm --server" from the /opt/server_workdir. Since I did everything as sudo, there seemed to be some weird permissions issues and it didn't like writing to the database. Once I did a normal mkdir and run as a non-privileged user, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was due to my running beeswarm under sudo. Once I ran it as a non-privileged user it worked fine. I apologize for the post.